Multiple event with MultiBlocProvider
I have 3 buttons at the top of screen - Latest, Saved & My Feed
I am using MultiBlocProvider where I am loading categories (works fine) and then Latest posts (loading fine initially).
Problem arises when clicking on Saved or My Feed to load their posts.
Here is code:
Job_post_state.dart
enum JobPostEvent { latest, saved, myFeed }

enum JobPostStatus { initial, loading, loaded, empty, failed }

class JobPostState {
  final List<PostDataModel> jobPosts;
  final JobPostStatus status;


  JobPostState({required this.jobPosts, this.status = JobPostStatus.initial});
  JobPostState copyWith({List<PostDataModel>? jobPosts, JobPostStatus? status}) {
    return JobPostState(jobPosts: jobPosts ?? [], status: status ?? this.status);
  }
}

job_post_bloc.dart
class JobPostBloc extends Bloc<JobPostEvent, JobPostState> {
  final JobPostRepository jobPostRepository;
  JobPostBloc({required this.jobPostRepository}) : super(JobPostState(status: JobPostStatus.initial, jobPosts: [])) {
    on<JobPostEvent>((event, emit) async {
      emit(state.copyWith(status: JobPostStatus.loading));
      print('bloc event: $event');
      switch (event) {
        case JobPostEvent.latest:
          try {
            final jobPosts = await jobPostRepository.getJobPosts();
            emit(state.copyWith(
                jobPosts: jobPosts,
                status: jobPosts.isEmpty ? JobPostStatus.empty : JobPostStatus
                    .loaded)
            );
          } catch (e) {
            emit(state.copyWith(status: JobPostStatus.failed));
          }
          break;
        case JobPostEvent.saved:
          try {
            final jobPosts = await Sqlite().fetchPosts();
            emit(state.copyWith(
                jobPosts: jobPosts,
                status: jobPosts.isEmpty ? JobPostStatus.empty : JobPostStatus
                    .loaded)
            );
          } catch (e) {
            emit(state.copyWith(status: JobPostStatus.failed));
          }
          break;
        case JobPostEvent.myFeed:
          try {
            final jobPosts = await jobPostRepository.getJobPosts();
            emit(state.copyWith(
                jobPosts: jobPosts,
                status: jobPosts.isEmpty ? JobPostStatus.empty : JobPostStatus
                    .loaded)
            );
          } catch (e) {
            emit(state.copyWith(status: JobPostStatus.failed));
          }
          break;
      }
    });
  }

job_list_screen.dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => StateBloc(JobPostRepository())
            ..add(FetchCategories()),
          lazy: false,
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => JobPostBloc(jobPostRepository: JobPostRepository())
            ..add(JobPostEvent.latest),
          lazy: false,
        ),
    ],
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: AppColor.appWhite,
        body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                /// Top bar with search & user button
                Common().sizeBox(40),
                AppTopBar(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (builder) => const ProfileScreen()
                        )
                    );
                  },
                  showLogin: true,
                ),
                const Divider(height: 1, color: AppColor.greyBottomBorder),
                /// Latest Jobs, Saved Jobs, My Feed & Filter
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
/// *Problem is here when tapped on each button, JobPostBloc event is not called*
/// *I want to change the post based on button tapped*
/// *Latest button to display posts from API & Saved button to display locally saved posts*

/// ***** onTapped(String text) is called for each button -- shared below*****
/// Latest button
                    _buildTextButtonWithDivider(AppText.btnLatestJob, displayLatestDivider),
/// Saved button
                    _buildTextButtonWithDivider(AppText.btnSavedJob, displaySavedDivider),
/// My feed button
                    _buildTextButtonWithDivider(AppText.btnMyFeed, displayMyFeedDivider),
                    IconButton(onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (builder) => AdvanceSearchScreen(),
                              fullscreenDialog: true
                          )
                      );
                    }, icon: AppImageWidget(imageName: AppImage.postFilter),
                      style: IconButton.styleFrom(
                        minimumSize: Size(30, 30),
                        maximumSize: Size(35, 35),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                BlocBuilder<StateBloc, StateState>(
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot is StateLoading) {
                        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                      } else if (snapshot is StateError) {
                        return Center(child: Text(snapshot.errorMessage),);
                      } else if (snapshot is CategoryLoaded) {
                        return categoryChipList(snapshot.categories);
                      }
                      return const Center(child: Text('No category found'),);
                    }
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: BlocBuilder<JobPostBloc, JobPostState>(
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        switch (snapshot.status) {
                          case JobPostStatus.loading:
                            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                          case JobPostStatus.failed:
                            return Center(child: Text('Error:'));
                          case JobPostStatus.loaded:

                            return ListView.builder(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                itemCount: snapshot.jobPosts.length ?? 0,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  PostDataModel post = snapshot.jobPosts[index];
                                  return JobCard(
                                    isTapped: false,
                                    isBookmarkTapped: false,
                                    post: post,
                                    onTap: () {
                                      print('push tapped');
                                      Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) => JobDetailView(jobModel: post),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                    postDeletedSetter: (result) {},
                                  );
                                }
                            );
                          case JobPostStatus.empty:
                            return const Center(
                              child: Text('Search for job'),
                            );
                          default:
                            return const Center(
                              child: Text('Search for job'),
                            );
                        }
                      }
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }

void onTapped(String text) {
      switch (text) {
        case AppText.btnLatestJob:
          context.read<JobPostBloc>().add(JobPostEvent.latest);
          displayLatestDivider = true;
          displaySavedDivider = false;
          displayMyFeedDivider = false;
          break;
        case AppText.btnSavedJob:
          context.read<JobPostBloc>().add(JobPostEvent.saved);
          displayLatestDivider = false;
          displaySavedDivider = true;
          displayMyFeedDivider = false;
          break;
        case AppText.btnMyFeed:
          context.read<JobPostBloc>().add(JobPostEvent.myFeed);
          displayLatestDivider = false;
          displaySavedDivider = false;
          displayMyFeedDivider = true;
          break;
      }
  }

